# How to check font-size in IE6+

Tags: testing, internet-explorer-6

I am wondering is there any way we can test the font size/color of a webpage in IE6+. I think it is not possible by checking the css class, as some other style may overwrite the styles of the class which has been assinged to that text.

Actually I want to know the browser assigned font-size to the text of the page, as we can do it in firebug on firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can. If you turn on `developer tools` - it's in every IE6.

Comment: I don't have IE6 anymore, but since when did IE6 have **developer tools**?

Comment: Since... I don't know really. I'm 100% positive that at least official virtual image with IE6 has it bundled - you just turn it on somewhere deep in settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you can try the only famous web developer toolbar for IE:

**[Internet Explorer Web Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)**